# A science-fictiony word/phrase for "small child"

Tags: single-word-requests, science

I'm looking for a word for "kid" or "child" that would apply (somewhat comically) in a space-age science-fiction setting.

Comment: This is where you get to make up any word you like in your story.  You could call them ***newlings*** or maybe those are just babies and ***younglings*** are kids.  The future hasn’t arrived yet so nobody knows what they will be called. This is therefore. Primarily Opinion Based.

Comment: @Jim thing is, I'm not writing a story -- I'm looking for a word with which to be funny in a presentation. I was hoping maybe Star Trek had some word for it already. In any case, I do agree that making one up is just as viable.

Comment: @khaverim That sort of exchange is exactly why the single-word-request tag asks you to be specific about the intended use of the word. Otherwise people put in effort which won't ever be fruitful for you. Could you edit your question in accordance with the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the Star Wars prequel movies referred to the youthful Jedi padawans as `younglings`. You could also call them `sprites`, `littles`, `halflings`, `bits`, `spawn`, `munchkins`, or `gremlins` off the top of my head. They aren't all spacey sounding but generally slightly humorous in my view. Or if you are thinking more Star Trek, what about some variation on `tribbles`?

Answer (score 1):

How about "sprog"?

> NOUN
>
> British
>
> informal, humorous
>
> A child.

Also sounds a little "space-age" in my opinion.

Comment: Nice find but it seems a little crude (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sprog) -- I want to avoid indecency :-)

Comment: "Sprog" is not considered indecent in any way in British English.